# Tasker cannot "Restore Backup" XML document?

Tags: xml, tasker

I took a tasker backup a while back, and it's in the XML file below. I need to restore it but it says "Could Not Be restored, sorry :). How do I repair this?

Tasker reinstalled, cleared data

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="5.6">
<Project sr="proj0" ve="2">
    <cdate>1552407651357</cdate>
    <mdate>1552412687410</mdate>
    <name>Base</name>
    <tids>6</tids>
    <Img sr="icon" ve="2">
        <nme>mw_action_home</nme>
    </Img>
</Project>
<Task sr="task6">
    <cdate>1552411186929</cdate>
    <edate>1552455082301</edate>
    <id>6</id>
    <nme>Thing</nme>
    <pri>100</pri>
    <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
        <code>548</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">Emergency Mode Activating. Power off phone 
to cancel!</Str>
        <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
        <code>905</code>
        <Int sr="arg0" val="3"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act2" ve="7">
        <code>902</code>
        <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg1" val="18"/>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act3" ve="7">
        <code>548</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%LOC</Str>
        <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act4" ve="7">
        <code>410</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">DCIM/emergencythingstuff.txt</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">Require Law Enforcement at %LOC ASAP.</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="1"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act5" ve="7">
        <code>101</code>
        <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">emergencysgsgsvsgvsgs</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="1"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="1"/>
        <Str sr="arg5" ve="3">320x240</Str>
        <Int sr="arg6" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg7" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg8" val="1"/>
        <Int sr="arg9" val="0"/>
    </Action>
</Task>
</TaskerData>
```

It should restore, but it won't for some reason. This is for a Science Fair. Is something wrong with the XML code or something?

Answer (score 0):

the xml looks good, is this a full backup? or just an exported project?
one would be .xml and the other would be .prj.xml

if it is just an exported project then you will have to import it, not restore backup.

Comment: i meant to put that as a comment, not an answer.
iirc, in order to restore a backup after a fresh install, you must first create a new backup, then go to restore and choose your old backup.